# Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection Save Credentials not working

Tags: windows, desktop

Trying to connect from Windows 7 to a Remote Windows 2008 Server via Remote Desktop Connection

I always used to be asked for credentials during logon – even though i saved my credentials

This error would creep up

Your system administrator does not allow the use of saved credentials to logon to the remote computer 
computername/ipadress because its identity is not fully verified. Please enter new credentials.
The logon attempt failed

There is no-trust-relationship when connecting 2 computers from different domains. Windows uses NTLM in this case and the default domain machine policy does not allow use of saved credentials.

Comment: Duplicated this question onto [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/604483/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working/606237?noredirect=1#606237). There's no solution to the problem; but at least there people won't close it without explanation.

Answer (score 70):

**Try these Below Steps:**

1. On your local machine Open Windows command prompt type: gpedit.msc -> Press Enter -> a new window will popout
2. Go to Local Computer Policy –> Computer Configuration –> Administrative Templates –> System –> Credentials Delegation
3. Double Click on “Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication”
4. By default it will be “not configured”
5. You will see radio buttons -> Enable the policy
6. Click the “Show” button in the options window below and enter the value “TERMSRV/*”  (without quotes) into the list.
7. Click Apply button
8. Do the same thing for the following policies:
        
   Allow Delegating Saved Credentials
        
   Allow Delegating Default Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication
        
   Allow Delegating Default Credentials
9. Make sure that "**Deny** Delegating Saved Credentials" is not enabled or does not contain “TERMSRV/*” in the list
10. Close all windows
11. Open a command prompt and use “gpupdate /force” command to apply the policy directly.

Comment: Seems not working, if connecting by IP not by hostname.

Comment: Thank you.
I'd like to add that it's possible to add it directly to the registry.
You can use the following key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation

Comment: more information about adding it directly to the registry:
https://serverfault.com/a/999666/257494